# LoopbackJs Call After Save Operation Hook only once

Tags: loopbackjs, loopback

I have model with createdOn and lastUpdatedOn fields in my PersitedModel which are basically dates.I am updating this on the `after save` operation hook. This is what MyModel.js looks like.

```
module.exports = function(MyModel) {
  MyModel.observe('after save', function(ctx, next) {
    if (ctx.instance && ctx.isNewInstance) {
      ctx.instance.updateAttribute('createdOn', new Date());
    }
    if (ctx.instance && !ctx.isNewInstance) {
      ctx.instance.updateAttribute('lastUpdatedOn', new Date());
    }
    next();
 });
}
```

Now the operation hook keeps calling this method.And Causes my app to crash.

```
<--- Last few GCs --->

441366 ms: Mark-sweep 1279.7 (1410.5) -> 1279.7 (1410.5) MB, 1093.9 / 0.0 ms [allocation failure] [GC in old space requested].
442456 ms: Mark-sweep 1279.7 (1410.5) -> 1279.7 (1410.5) MB, 1090.7 / 0.0 ms [allocation failure] [GC in old space requested].
443606 ms: Mark-sweep 1279.7 (1410.5) -> 1286.6 (1403.5) MB, 1148.8 / 0.0 ms [last resort gc].
444735 ms: Mark-sweep 1286.6 (1403.5) -> 1293.7 (1403.5) MB, 1129.2 / 0.0 ms [last resort gc].


<--- JS stacktrace --->

==== JS stack trace =========================================

Security context: 00000173CF3CFB49 <JS Object>
```

If I remove the code for update of lastUpdatedOn then it works fine.So the problem basically that I am facing is the operation hook keeps calling the method.Is there a way to prevent this.Am I doing something wrong.? I want to call this method only once

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your use-case, you should try using a mixin instead of model hooks. Loopback has some [documentation](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb2/Defining-mixins.html) on how you can make your own. There's also one that you can use for this on npm: https://www.npmjs.com/package/loopback-ds-timestamp-mixin

Comment: This Looks like the best way to go.However For now I have implemented using only before save hook
MyModel.observe('before save', function(ctx, next) {
    if (ctx.instance && ctx.isNewInstance) {
      ctx.instance.createdOn = new Date();
    }
    if (ctx.data && !ctx.isNewInstance) {
      ctx.data.lastUpdatedOn = new Date();
    }
    next();
  });

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I cannot put a comment ...

You can try before save for creation and after save for update, the date for creation it won't be a big difference

```
module.exports = function(MyModel) {  

    MyModel.observe('before save', function(ctx, next) {
        if (ctx.instance && ctx.isNewInstance) {
          ctx.instance.updateAttribute('createdOn', new Date());
        }        
        next();
     });

    MyModel.observe('after save', function(ctx, next) {
       if (ctx.instance && !ctx.isNewInstance) {
          ctx.instance.updateAttribute('lastUpdatedOn', new Date());
        }      
        next();
     });

}
```

Comment: Yes I finally ended up implementing using only before save hook
Channel.observe('before save', function(ctx, next) {
    if (ctx.instance && ctx.isNewInstance) {
      ctx.instance.createdOn = new Date();
    }
    if (ctx.data && !ctx.isNewInstance) {
      ctx.data.lastUpdatedOn = new Date();
    }
    next();
  });

However the mixin solution by @nVitius seems like the best way to proceed.

Comment: @DhruvDatt good to learn you found a solution, thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at this: https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Operation-hooks.html#operation-options

Basically, you can pass options as the last argument to any Model operation, which can then be read by the Hook.